# Why am I not finding values of an iterator?

Tags: java

Why does this code not print values with a `"q"` in them?

```
Iterator<String> it = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().contains("q"))
         System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Output:

```
Pacific/Kwajalein
Etc/GMT-3
America/Martinique
Pacific/Funafuti
Canada/Pacific
Eire
America/Sitka
Brazil/West
US/Aleutian
```

Comment: Hint: *every* time you call `next()`, it reads another string. You're reading one, checking whether it contains "q", then (if so) reading the *next* string and printing it out... you want to call `next()` *once* on each iteration of the loop...

Comment: You're iterating twice. You check the next value in the 'if' and then take the value _after_ that for printing.

Answer (score 5):

Every time you call `next()` you read the next item, but you’re calling `next()` *again* when printing, so you’re printing the next item of ones with a `q` in them.

Java provides a convenient syntax for this situation; the *foreach loop*:

```
for (String zoneId : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
     if (zoneId.contains("q")) {
        System.out.println(zoneId);
     }
}
```

Or more recently, streams:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
  .filter(zoneId -> zoneId.contains("q"))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you iterate past the entry with `'q'` in it.  The first `it.next()` moves the iterator and returns the object.  Then inside the `if` you move the iterator again and print the element that is one after the one with the `'q'` in it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you call `next()` two times. Every time when you do this, you read **the next** value from the `Iterator`. Check this out:

```
Iterator<String> it = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String zoneId = it.next();

    if (zoneId.contains("q"))
        System.out.println(zoneId);
}
```

You can do the same using more readable syntax with `for loop`:

```
for (String zoneId : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds())
    if (zoneId.contains("q"))
        System.out.println(zoneId);
```

Or, probably, using `Stream`:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
      .filter(zoneId -> zoneId.contains("q"))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The results of all snippets are the same.